# Position legend on bottom in HTML5

Tags: html, css, legend

Previously `legend`-tags had an `align` property with the values `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right`. But in HTML 5 this property is not supported anymore. W3schools [advises to use css](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_legend.asp) instead.

But how can you use css to position the legend to the bottom of the fieldset, so that it looks like this:

Edit: Just to clearify: I don't mean that the `legend` tag is not supported im HTML 5, but the `align` property does not exist anymore. And I want to position the legend on the bottom of the fieldset.

[image]

Comment: The `<legend>` element is [alive and well](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/legend). Where did you hear it's not supported?

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML and CSS to help [demonstrate your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Frankly; this looks like you're actually using `legend` for the wrong purpose.

Comment: I did the following which also works when you have a background image and use transparency https://codepen.io/ETACS/pen/abOaJNa

Answer (score 7):

You need to manually position the `legend`.

```css
fieldset {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid black 1px;
}

legend {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
  padding: 0 5px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend>Legend</legend>
    Content goes here.
</fieldset>
```

```css
fieldset {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  font-size: 32px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid black 1px;
}

legend {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 4px; /* manually repositioned to better align the text along the border */
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
  padding: 0 5px;
  font-family: arial black;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: transparent;
  background: red; /* acts like the color property */
 -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Legend</legend>
  Content goes here.
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Biggest problem I have with this is that it only works if the background is indeed white.

Comment: @Salketer why `background-color` a problem? you can change the color to whatever you want. there is another way to accomplish this, but the code is more verbose/hack-ish

Comment: Because in my case this is applied on a background-image so that looks odd.

Comment: @Salketer ive edited my code. you can accomplish what you want as long as you do not mind a border running between the letters 'legend'; you could also achieve an affect like the top one by creating another element inside `fieldset` that has the same height as the border and place that to cover only the border, but you would also end up covering the picture too. you could prolly use similar code to my 2nd example to avoid that issue too though